# How do I validate certain inputs based on a checkbox?

Tags: jquery, validation

all im building a competition page and im having trouble with validation, to enter the competition we ask for first name, last name & email if you want to recommend a friend you click the checkbox which shows another form where you enter your friends details and that again has recommend a friend so a third form appears, etc.

Now when it comes to validating the form Im trying to basically say that if checkbox is checked validate fields form 1 & 2, if checkbox2 is checked validate fields 1,2 & 3, and finally if checkbox3 is checked validate fields 1,2,3 & 4

Ive tried to get around the validation with a jQuery if statement see below, onSubmit it returns a true or false value from this function:

```
function validateForm() {
                if( $('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                    if( $('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) { 
                       { 
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["fname"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#fname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["lname"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#lname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                        var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                          if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
                            $('input#email').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            console.log('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["f_name"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#fname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["l_name"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#lname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var email = document.getElementById('se_email').value;
                        var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                          if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
                            console.log('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
                            $('input#se_email').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["fr_name"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#fname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["fr_lname"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#lname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var email = document.getElementById('fr_email').value;
                        var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                          if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
                            console.log('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
                            $('input#fr_email').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }

                    } else {
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["fname"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#fname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["lname"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#lname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                        var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                          if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
                            $('input#email').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            console.log('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["f_name"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#fname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["l_name"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#lname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var email = document.getElementById('se_email').value;
                        var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                          if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
                            console.log('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
                            $('input#se_email').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["fr_name"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#fname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var x = document.forms["competition"]["fr_lname"].value;
                        if (x == null || x == "") {
                            $('input#lname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                        var email = document.getElementById('fr_email').value;
                        var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                          if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
                            console.log('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
                            $('input#fr_email').css("border","solid red 2px");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    var x = document.forms["competition"]["fname"].value;
                    if (x == null || x == "") {
                        $('input#fname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var x = document.forms["competition"]["lname"].value;
                    if (x == null || x == "") {
                        $('input#lname').css("border","solid red 2px");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                      if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
                        console.log('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Demo is available here http://pi.mrjoshfisher.com/comp/

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, rather make a small example of what you want in jsfiddle, you will get an answer much quicker than posting a big block of code.

Comment: @Chris that would be helpful thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just hiding and showing (instead of creating) the 2nd, 3rd or nth element then you can simply just add or remove classes to the elements within those divs once their `display` attribute changes, say to a `validateable` class.

You don't really need to check for the checkbox value on the form submit, just make sure that each time a checkbox changes its value you bind the `change` method and add the `validateable` class to the proper elements within that group. Then on your submit you grab all the `validateable` inputs and check if they are empty.

### Update:

I added [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gusrub/4vy2efmm/) with a demo with your code. Note that I changed/simplified some stuff.